# Possible to set Forgotten Password path in config?

Tags: users, config, login, password

Looking at the documentation here: https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/config-settings.html#users

I have set `loginPath`, `invalidUserTokenPath` and `setPasswordPath`. However, it appears that there isn't a config option for the forgotten password template.

It's also not mentioned as an option (unlike the other path options mentioned above) on this doc: https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/templating/forgot-password-form.html

EDIT: Forgot to add that I have got it working in the meantime by setting 
`{{ url('users/forgotten-password') }}` in my login template.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this is because Craft never needs to get there by itself.  It's a page you will always link to in one of your templates.  So in theory, you can simply link directly to your Forgotten password template, like you did already.

Comment: I think you’re right. It’s a page that isn’t automated by craft. Cheers for confirming.